# What is the noun for "implore"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, synonyms, vocabulary

What is the noun form of the word "implore"?

I saw some suggestions online for "imploration", but this seems awkward to me.

Comment: *Imploration* is correct.  Sounding awkward doesn't trump the fact that that is the only noun form given in dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe just "imploring".  *Her imploring did not convince her father to relax her curfew.*

Comment: @GEdgar - *imploring* is not a noun, but adv. How about "Her adjuration did not convince ..."

Comment: Imploring is a gerund; can behave much like a noun.

Comment: "Plea" can be used in all these contexts and has the advantage of being understood. Take a look at JeffSahol's answer, below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use *plea*, rather than trying to gerundize it.

Comment: This is the right choice, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The OED has an entry for *imploration*, but if you don't like it, the *-ing* form of the verb, *imploring* may be possible in some contexts.

Comment: Yes, [*imploration*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=imploration&ls=a) is the noun form, although that word doesn't seem to be in vogue these days.

Comment: Which is to say the "-ing" form can be a gerund, not just an adv., so that it can be used in a place where a noun is required, right?

Comment: @Kris: The '-ing' form of a verb can, depending on the verb, be a noun, an adjective or a verb. 'Imploring', for example, is a noun in the sentence 'All my imploring was useless'.

Comment: True. However, per Carlo the  OAD defines it only as an adj., so he'd suggest it cannot be a noun. (see answer by Carlo)

Comment: @Kris: The noun 'imploring' has its own entry in the OED where it is defined as 'Supplication, beseeching'.

Comment: True. Carlo cites the OAD, though, not the OED. The pond!

Comment: @Kris: I think it's more likely to be that the OED is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

"Imploration."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imploration

I believe its use frequency is "rare", and people seem to prefer the gerund version or even a synonym. However, for artistic and connotative reasons, I would prefer to make this word more popular.